# Unable to set the cron job schedule in application properties. SpringBoot ;scheduling of cron job at runtime using Scheduler

Tags: spring-boot, cron, spring-scheduled

I am trying to schedule my rest service(with  GET method) using

`@Scheduled(cron = xyzzy.getTimeSchedule())`

The schedule details are expected to be obtained from application properties from cloud during the application start up. however I get "The value for Annotation attribute Scheduled.cron must be  a constant expression" compile time error. Please suggest. Also what might be the underlying issue like with the Spring annotation and the properties being available during the time application start up. Please guide or direct me to understand.TIA.

Comment: did you check my answer? Just curious,... If you find helpful/unnecessary/need-to-update/unrelated-answer, please let me know.

Comment: Hi, Shekhar Rai , I did check your answer. Thank you for your response. However my scenario is a  little different in the sense that I get my properties (Key : Value  pair) from the cloud via a method annotated with @Property annotation , and it's throwing "The value for Annotation attribute Scheduled.cron must be a constant expression" compile time error. I'm sure it has something to do with `@Scheduled ` and availability of properties at the start up of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this is what worked for me.
I have my property stored as key : value pair over the cloud.like so..

`xyz.Schedule = */5 * * * * ;`

`public Class testController {`

`@Autowired`
`private Type type;`

`@Scheduled(cron = "${type.getSchedule()}")`
`@GetMapping(path = "/", produces = "application/json")`
`public void getmethod() { blah blah } }`

I ran my application successfully and was being able to populate the property configured over cloud at the start of application, and was able to get response for my api as well.

Things I tried:
As suggested by Shekhar Rai in this discussion chain, declaring it as final variable, but was unable to access it in my method.

tried wrapping the method as a runnable task, couldn't do so.

arrived at: @Scheduled.cron always expects a constant parameter(like a string), but get() is dynamic , therefore wrapped it as a constant parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Using [@Scheduled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) annotation you cannot provide a method for cron-expression which comes from the cloud. As java annotation needs *constant-expression*, which is a variable whose value cannot change once it has been assigned. For that, you need to use `final` keyword.

```
public static final String TIME_SCHEDULE = "0 0/30 8-10 * * *";
```

Then use that constant expression in your scheduler method,

```
@Scheduled(cron = TIME_SCHEDULE)
```

In your case, you should go for [@TaskScheduler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html) (from doc)

> Task scheduler interface that abstracts the scheduling of Runnables based on different kinds of triggers.
>   This interface is separate from SchedulingTaskExecutor since it usually represents for a different kind of backend, i.e. a thread pool with different characteristics and capabilities. Implementations may implement both interfaces if they can handle both kinds of execution characteristics.

**Replacing @Scheduled annotation with @TaskScheduler**

First, autowire TaskScheduler and make sure that you annotated your main class with [@EnableScheduling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html) annotation to provide bean for TaskScheduler.

```
@Autowired 
private TaskScheduler scheduler;
```

Now you need to schedule providing Runnable and [CronTrigger](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronTrigger.html) arguments. It schedules the given Runnable, invoking it whenever the trigger indicates a next execution time.

That means you need to wrap your logic(currently this is the code from your @Schduled method body) into Runnable instance. And your `xyzzy.getTimeSchedule()` should be provided to CronTrigger constructor.

```
Runnable runnableTask = () -> {
   //call REST API here
};

scheduler.schedule(runnableTask, new CronTrigger(xyzzy.getTimeSchedule());
```

> Now you get rid of *"The value for Annotation attribute Scheduled.cron must be a constant expression"*

Comment: Shekhar Rai, Yes have been reading along similar lines of TaskScheduler , I believe that would work for my scenario.Will update if this resolves my issue. Until then thank you for your time and knowledge share on this. I will vote for your response on this once I implement it .

Comment: So, here is the deal, my logic which I need to wrap into Runnable instance is a REST api call (GET method),  which basically gets some response .I need to schedule that api call periodically using the cron job.

Comment: @crcrcr You mean you are having trouble to wrap in Runnable? BTW I have updated my answer. or you can update your question putting your rest call(if needed). :)

Comment: Thank you for your continued response on this. I have posted , that worked for my case.However I would still be interested in knowing wrapping my api call as a runnable task in a bit more detail.also do let me know how could I give credit for your time and knowledge share ?

Comment: Great! Saw your answer as well! In that case, you have both `Scheduler` and `GET` API exposing for the same method - seems a little bit confusing for me as they are different mechanisms for different purposes - but as you have achieved what you're trying to do, that's fair good! I suggest you read more about them and I personally prefer to separate them.

`wrapping rest API call in instance` - I meant to call `REST API` using `http-client` or similar libraries in the body of Runnable instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ManagedConfiguration
private ConfigClass configClass;
    
@bean
public String getSchedulerValue() {
return configClass.getSchedule();}

@Scheduled(cron="#{getSchedulerValue}")
```

Comment: Since last answered, this is the refactored code for this context and this works great !!

Comment: Answer's are great. But for best practices, please provide an explanation. You only posting code makes the OP and future commers copy and paste your answer without understanding the logic behind the answer. Please provide an answer with some explanation. Thank You!